# Segmentation Fault in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I get the following error when running `swift run` inside of an executable Swift Package:

```
zsh: segmentation fault  swift run
```

I have been able to boil the code down to the following:

```swift
enum MyEnum {
    case FirstCase
    case SecondCase
    case Other
}

struct MyEnumCollection {
    private var enums: [MyEnum]
}

extension MyEnumCollection: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    public init() {
        self.enums = []
    }
}

extension MyEnumCollection: Collection {
    public var startIndex: Int {
        0
    }

    public var endIndex: Int {
        self.enums.count
    }

    public subscript(position: Int) -> MyEnum {
        return self.enums[position]
    }

    public func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        return self.enums.index(after: i)
    }
}

var collection = MyEnumCollection()

collection.append(MyEnum.FirstCase)
```

The segmentation fault happens on the last line, at the `append` statement.

Can someone help me understand why this is happening and how I should fix this?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection: To add RangeReplaceableCollection conformance to your custom collection, add an empty initializer and the replaceSubrange(_:with:) method to your custom type.

Comment: @MartinR Aha! That solves it indeed. Weird that Swift doesn't complain about it not being implemented.

Comment: A similar (same?) problem was observed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64086965/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, looks like the same problem

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? It seems like [this particular commit](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/6b219a9c565e57b7fdf95633a00ae2755820700b) fixes the bug, and it is tagged with the version 5.6. (I don't have 5.6 right now to test it out though)

Comment: @Sweeper I'm not using 5.6 yet as well, my current version is 5.5.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update*

Thanks to a comment from @MartinR it turns out that a even better solution is to implement `replaceSubrange(_:with:)` from the `RangeReplaceableCollection` protocol *instead* of `append`

```
mutating func replaceSubrange<C>(_ subrange: Range<Int>, with newElements: C) where C : Collection, MyEnum == C.Element {
    self.enums.replaceSubrange(subrange, with: newElements)
}
```

---

*Old solution*

You need to implement `append()` as well

```
public mutating func append(_ newElement: MyEnum) {
    enums.append(newElement)
}
```

There is a default implementation of this function but of course it has no knowledge about your internal data source `enums` so it is not usable.

---

Going forward you might also need to implement other functions that has a default implementation.

Another thing, personally I would use the properties of the `Array` class as well when conforming to the protocol.

```
public var startIndex: Int {
    return enums.startIndex
}

public var endIndex: Int {
    return self.enums.endIndex
}
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, one should implement `replaceSubrange(_:with:)` (and then `append()` should work as well).

Comment: @MartinR  Interesting thing is, OP's code should have produced a compile-time error, because of this issue that was fixed ([SR-6501](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6501)). However, I am still able to reproduce it.

Comment: @Sweeper can you refile the bug? Any segfault in the compiler is a bug.

Comment: @Sweeper it looks like it should have been resolved about a year ago. It doesn't say in which Swift version it is resolved though. Also, thanks for the the start- and endIndex tip

Comment: @matt It's not a segfault in the compiler, but infinite recursion when the code is run. Also I only have version 5.5.1, and there is a chance that it is only fixed in 5.6 (though the resolved date of the bug is before the release date of 5.5.1).

Comment: @MartinR I added that function and removed my `append` implementation and it works fine. This is interesting since RangeReplaceableCollection inherits from Collection so one has to read the documentation really carefully when creating a custom type like this. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Apparently the issue (which was also observed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64088034/1187415) has not properly been fixed.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks, I have Xcode 13.3 / Swift 5.6 and was able to reproduce the issue. And I can confirm that the solution above does fix the issue.